# PhpStorm unresolved variable on Vue.js template

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I have an object called `Products` which is a parameter of another object called `List`.

Now then I loop through the products object in Vue.js template part, IDE always shows that it cannot see any products parameter. It looks like this:

```
<tbody v-if="list.products" v-for="product in list.products">
  <p>{{ product.id }}</p>
  <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
</tbody>
```

In this case `id` and `title` is unresolved by IDE.

list variable is initialized like this:

```
private list: ListData = this.listData;
```

ListData interface:

```
interface ListData {
  products: Products
}
```

Products interface:

```
interface Products {
  [index: number]: Product
  length: number
}
```

Product interface:

```
interface Product {
  id: number
  title: string
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": ["assets/**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

The whole component looks like this:

```
@Component
export default class ProductsList {
  @Prop({ default: () => {} }) listData!: ListData

  private list: ListData = this.listData;
}
```

I set the `listData` as a new list variable because I need to mutate the data inside it, and I can't mutate the `prop` directly. But even if I use `listData` variable directly in the template - IDE still doesn't see it's properties. Of course the Vue.js plugin is installed.

So the problem is that IDE shows that `list.products` variables are unresolved. Instead, it should direct into the Product interface.

Comment: A Vue template typically only has access to `props` or `data` or `methods` or `computed` defined on the component. *Where* exactly are you initialising `list`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-50459](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50459) to be notified on any progress with this ticket